# A tooltip widget/plugin in YUI3

Tags: yui3

I am writing an app and I want stack overflow like tool-tips updated with ajax. And I want it in AJAX too.

Please tell me if any such library already exists and otherwise will it be helpful to write a one from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two solutions

1. The YUI3 Alloy Tooltip module. Which is poorly written and not suitable for my use.
2. The example provided by YUI3 http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/widget/widget-tooltip.html

It is helpful and customizable.

Comment: Great answer... Agreed that Alloy is horribly implemented.